# Using Average Exchange Rate in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I want to use monthly average exchange rate in Suitlet, in place where there is a api call : nlapiExchangeRate.

To achieve this, built a currency type saved search (using a hack way of creating it) which takes base and transaction ccy and uses group by and average to calculate the exchange rate. The plan was to call this saved search in the suitlet where there is api call.

Now I am stuck as the saved search cant be located by the suitlet. Have any of you guys done anything like this before ? What approach did you use ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load the Saved Search with:

```
var savedsearch = nlapiLoadSearch('currency', id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your search is public.

Use below code to run your search.

```
nlapiLoadSearch(null, searchId).runsearch();
```

Or alternatively,

```
nlapiSearchRecord('currency', id)
```